# How work template inheritance for Pug/Jade?

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

I have problem with template inheritance (more precisely with - **block css** ).
I have nested templates: template.pug -> index.pug -> contactContainer.pug

Every file has **block css**. And template.pug get all block css by index.pug and contactContainer.pug (it is right), but in html duplicate contactContainer.css:

```
<div id="leftColumn">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/layouts/main/contactContainer.css">
  <div id="contactContainer">
    <div id="concatSubcontainer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think problem by I use "**include**" instead "**extends**", but so i'm not sure because I have little experience for Pug.

Example my files:

**template.pug** (main template file)

```
doctype html
html
    head
        include ./head
        block css
        block js

    body
        div(id="page")
            include ./header
            block body
            include ./footer
```

**index.pug** (body file)

```
extends layouts/main/template

block append css
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/index.css")    
block body
    div(id="mainContainer")

        div(id="leftColumn")
            include ./layouts/main/contactContainer

        div(id="rightColumn")
            include ./layouts/main/selfContainer
```

**contactContainer.pug** (template for *leftColumn*)

```
block append css
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/layouts/main/contactContainer.css')

div(id="contactContainer")
    div(id="concatSubcontainer")
```

Comment: Have you read the pug documentation?  https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand what do you mean. Use simple <link href="style.css"> without "block css"? But in that case style.css added to body (correct practice - add css files to head).

Comment: I am only pointing out that the answer to your question can be found in the official documentation.